# Get Color and do Calculation

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, cell, background-color

I want to do this in C3:C5 - If the other cells (months) have the color green it will take the total minus the value green and if the cells are red don't do anything.

For Ex. - Project 2 - I have total 200 and at 01/01/15 have 1 cell with green and other reds so it will be 200-100=100 (value)

Project 3 - I have total 300 and at 01/02/15 and 01/03/15 have green so it will be 300-100-150=50 (at value)

I want to do it at VBA but Not necessary

[image: Image Link]

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try *(it is for green #4)*:

```
Sub Roeid()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To N
        v = Cells(i, "B").Value
        For Each a In Array("D", "E", "F", "G")
            If Cells(i, a).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
                v = v - Cells(i, a).Value
            End If
        Next a
        Cells(i, "C").Value = v
    Next i
End Sub
```